# For loop in batch file reading a file of File Paths

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I want to write a Windows batch file script that will loop through a text file of FILE PATHS, do some work using data from each file path, then ultimately delete the file.

I started by running the **FORFILES** command and sending its output (*the **@PATH** parameter is the full path of any file it matches*) to a text file (results.txt).

I end up with a results.txt file like this:

```
"C:/Windows/Dir1/fileA.log"
"C:/Windows/Dir1/fileA.log"
"C:/Windows/Dir2/fileC.log" 
"C:/Windows/Dir3/fileB.log"
```

What I want to do is:

- Use a FOR loop and read each line in the results.txt file
- For each line (file path), strip out the directory name that the log file is sitting in (ie: Dir1, Dir2, etc..) and create a directory with that SAME name in a different location (ie.  D:/Archive/Backups/Dir1, D:/Archive/Backups/Dir2, etc..) -- assuming the directory doesn't exist.
- Move the actual .log file to a zip file in that directory [I have code to do this].
- Delete the .log file from its original location.  [Pretty straightforward]

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to accomplish the first 2 steps.  My FOR loop seems to stop after reading the very first line:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 delims=\" %%G in ("results.txt") DO (
...
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to parse the path with the tokens/delims options because you don't know how many directory levels you are dealing with. You want to preserve each line in its entirety. TO parse the path you want to use the FOR variable modifiers. (type HELP FOR from the command line and look at the last section of the output)

%%~pG gives the path (without the drive or file name). If we then strip off the last `\`,  we can go through another FOR iteration and get the name (and possible extension) of the file's directory by using %%~nxA.

The toggling of delayed expansion is just to protect against a possible `!` in the path. If you know that no path contains `!` then you can simply enable delayed expansion at the top of the script and be done with it.

EDIT - this code has been modified significantly since Aacini pointed out that I misread the requirements. It should satisfy the requirements now.

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in ("results.txt") do (
  set "myPath=%~pG"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in ("!myPath:~0,-1!") do (
    endlocal
    if not exist d:\Archive\Backups\%%~nxA md d:\Archive\Backups\%%~nxA
    rem ::zip %%G into zip file in the D: location
    rem ::you should be able to create the zip with the move option
    rem ::so you don't have to del the file
  )
)
```

Comment: But none of the modifiers give the last directory in the path... In the example, the directory at D: is different than the one at C:

Comment: @Aacini - Ahh, I didn't read the problem carefully enough. I'll try again

Comment: Thanks @dbenham.  Just a minor correction -- the set myPath line doesn't need the double quotes around it.  Neither does the results.txt.  I'm not sure if it invalidates the results.txt but, definitely the myPath.  With those couple of corrections I was able to get any new dirs created AND the zipping should be very straightforward.

Comment: Oops = the leading quote was misplaced. It should work with the corrected quotes, as should the "results.txt" with "usebackq" option. But it should work just as well without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this to timestamp files before offloading to SFTP.

Hope you find it useful.

The timestamp coding may seem irrelevant to your issue, but I left it because it's a good example of dissecting the filename itself.

I suggest you put an ECHO in front of the REN command for testing.  Different shells may have different results.

In the end, the delayedexpansion command wasn't necessary.  It was the sub-routine that fixed my issues with variables inside the loop.  That could possibly be because of my OS ver. (Win 8.1)  -  It wouldn't hurt to leave it.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if %time:~0,2% geq 10 set TIMESTAMP=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
if %time:~0,2% leq 9  set TIMESTAMP=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_0%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

echo TimeStamp=%TIMESTAMP%
echo.

for %%G in (*.txt) do (
set OLDNAME=%%G
call :MXYZPTLK
)

dir *.txt

goto :EOF

:MXYZPTLK
echo OldName=%OLDNAME%
ren %OLDNAME% %OLDNAME:~0,-4%_%TIMESTAMP%%OLDNAME:~-4,4%
echo.

:END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two minor problems:

- The path separator in the file is '/' but you use '\' in the for loop.
- The quotes around "results.txt" stop it working.

This works.  Don't write quotes to results.txt and you won't get a quote at the end of the filename.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=3,4 delims=/" %%I in (results.txt) DO (
  REM Directory
  echo %%I
  REM File
  echo %%J
)
```